# Error in clearecase wile checking out a file

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, clearcase-remote-client, clearcase-automation

I have an issue with ClearCase I was trying to check out a file from the dir by using `ct co -nc file name`, but I am getting the following error:

```
cleartool: Error: branch type "test1" not found in VOB "/dir/file" and no global type definition can be found.
cleartool: Error: Unable to create branch requested by -mkbranch option in config spec.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out "file".
```

But when I was trying to check out another file from dir I am able to do them. I am only getting the problem to check out that file.

Can anyone help me how can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a config spec using a branch named "`test1`" in a selection rule (`element ... -mkbranch test1`) which was not created first.

So first, check what the config spec looks like:

```
cleartool catcs
```

See also what the config spec are for the files in the parent folder of that file:

```
cd /path/to/§parent/folder
cleartool ls
```

See if using [`cleartool mkbrtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm) would help:

```
cleartool mkbrtype -c "test1 branch" test1@/vobs/avob
```

(I use the Unix syntax, judging from your [previous config spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956212/6309))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "*test1*" branch type does not exist in the vob.

Create a branch using [ct mkbrtype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm). Run the following command form the folder where file is present

`ct mkbrtype -nc test1`

As the error is occurring only for one file, the config spec should have selection rule only for that file. Can check this using 
`ct catcs`

Note:- When adding a branch rule in config spec, Always check the brtype exists with that name.